# Blender 2.8 sculpt mode shows triangulated faces

Tags: sculpt

As the title says, when I switch to sculpt mode in Blender 2.8, the mesh I'm working on displays the faces as if they were triangulated. I'm sure I'm just missing a checkbox that's buried somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. Does anyone know what overlay or setting is causing this?
[image]

[image]

Update: To clarify, the mesh is not being triangulated, it is just displaying triangles when in sculpt mode.
[image]

Comment: Is the `Dyntopo`(Dynamic Topologies) setting on, check it in the Tool panel? It will force the face triangle.

Comment: Dyntopo is off. When I used Dyntopo before in 2.79 it actually triangulated the mesh and left it that way, but that's not what is happening here. What's happening for me in 2.8 is while in sculpt mode it is DISPLAYING triangles, but when switching back to object or edit mode it displays the normal quads.

Comment: I think it is a feature for accurately display. It tells you how render engine treat them by default. Or maybe just a bug..

Comment: Whether it's a bug or a feature, it's quite annoying because the triangulation calculation constantly shifts as you sculpt.

Comment: 2.8 no longer supports Subsurf for sculpting (2.79 had problems with displaying modifiers result but could work with that); probably it will be in the next versions. Use Multires modifier instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mr Zak, unfortunately that doesn't change anything in sculpt mode, and the Multires modifier doesn't play nice with the Solidify modifier (Multires doesn't allow Solidify first in the mod stack).

Comment: Also to clarify, this issue is not related to the modifiers I have on the mesh. When I remove all modifiers this "triangulation display" still occurs in sculpt mode. In the attached gif animation the modifiers are disabled, and the behavior is exactly the same when the modifiers are removed. This is not a modifier issue, it's an issue with sculpt mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of June 5th, this behavior is no longer present in the latest build of Blender 2.8 beta. I guess it was a bug that has now been fixed.

Comment: cool! you can then mark your own answer as accepted so the question gets closed.